# Support preLollipop devices at custom styles

Tags: android, styles

I am doing my custom style in Android and I want to know if is possible support this style in preLollipop devices.

Now, I have this .xml in values folder and I using Android Studio.

Any recommendation?

Thanks

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <style name="GradiantTheme" parent="android:Theme.DeviceDefault.Light.NoActionBar">

        <!-- App background color -->
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/theme_background</item>

        <!--Transparent status bar-->
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus" tools:targetApi="kitkat">true</item>


        <!--   texts -->
        <item name="android:textColor" tools:targetApi="lollipop">@color/gradiant</item>


        <!--   theme UI controls like checkboxes and text fields -->
        <item name="android:colorAccent" tools:targetApi="lollipop">@color/gradiant</item>


    </style>




</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

for older versions check two folders in your project as :
    **values-v11:**

```
    <!--
        Base application theme for API 11+. This theme completely replaces
        AppBaseTheme from res/values/styles.xml on API 11+ devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <!-- API 11 theme customizations can go here. -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

**values-v14:**

```
<resources>

    <!--
        Base application theme for API 14+. This theme completely replaces
        AppBaseTheme from BOTH res/values/styles.xml and
        res/values-v11/styles.xml on API 14+ devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- API 14 theme customizations can go here. -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

Answer (score -1):

Your default values folder will cater to only pre lollipop devices. If your create a values-v21 folder then the style in it will be specifically for devices supporting lollipop version. For example, you can put your lollipop transition effects in values-v21 folder's style xml because it will be supported by lollipop only. 
If you want to change the style only for pre lollipop devices then just make those changes in your style xml which is in your default values folder.
Hope the above description helps.

Comment: if you have downvoted, you have to care to explain why? The description that i have written is absolutely correct because i myself have implemented this!!